# how to set the quota of local storage cover all nova computes in openstack

Tags: storage, openstack, quota, libvirt, openstack-nova

The **ceph storage** could `set` and `show` by `openstack quota set[show]`, but where and how could I set the **local storage** capability of the **all nova computes** which has the **local storage** by `images_type = raw` in the **nova.conf**'s `[libvirt]` setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible.  Openstack doesn't support local disk quotas.

Local disk usage can be limited by the flavors that a project is permitted to use.  This means that it could *could* be controlled indirectly by instance or VCPU quotas.

For example, if you implemented your flavors with a (max) ratio of 10GB of local disk per VCPU, and limited the VCPUs per compute node to 64, you would be effectively limiting local disk usage to (max) 640GB.